Dockerfile for sqlite3 solving the error with better-sqlite3
in my project I need a Dockerfile for sqlite3 because I am using microservices with Kubernetes and Docker and on Windows and MacOS it gave me the same error when installing.
the project uses nodejs version 16, typeorm version 0.3.20, better-sqlite3 version ^9.4.1, I also need a deployment file for this project to use it with Kubernetes.
This is exactly the error when I try to install on my local machine:
# dalthon@MacBookPro in ~/Documents/project on git:main x [23:25:11] C:1
$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/2] ⠄ better-sqlite3
error /Users/dalthon/Documents/project/node_modules/better-sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild --release
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/dalthon/Documents/project/node_modules/better-sqlite3
Output:
prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=16.20.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
gyp info using node@16.20.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "/Users/dalthon/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /Users/dalthon/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dalthon/Documents/project/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dalthon/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.20.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/dalthon/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.20.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/dalthon/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.20.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/dalthon/Documents/project/node_modules/better-sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
    import gyp  # noqa: E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.version import StrictVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:284:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node" "/Users/dalthon/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dalthon/Documents/project/node_modules/better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok


Tho solve this error I found modified and generated this Dockerfile that uses node:16-slim
FROM node:16-slim

# Instalar dependencias necesarias para compilar better-sqlite3
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        python3 \
        make \
        g++ \
        sqlite3 \
        libsqlite3-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=prod && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]

The kubernetes deployment to access the database is this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sqliteproject-data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sqliteproject-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sqliteproject
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sqliteproject
        db: sqlite
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sqliteproject
          image: dalthonmh/sqliteproject
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              name: http
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sqlite-data
              mountPath: /app/data

        - name: sqlitebrowser
          image: lscr.io/linuxserver/sqlitebrowser:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: sqlite
            - containerPort: 3001
              name: sqlitessl
          env:
            - name: TZ
              value: "America/Lima"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sqlite-data
              mountPath: /app/data
              readOnly: false

      volumes:
        - name: sqlite-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: sqliteproject-data-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqliteproject-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: sqliteproject
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000

    - name: sqlite
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000


When I need to access to the sqlite3 database I use kubernetes port-forward
kubectl port-forward podname 3000:3000

and then go into the web browser in the port 3000. When I try to modify data for first time gave me the error "cant write because is only for read", to solve that y enable giving full access to the /app/data because it have the initial-db.sqlite file:
kubectl exec -it podname -c ingresante -- //bin//bash -c "chmod -R 777 ./data"

Note: Each time the pod is restarted, I need to run the enable command
